# Converging in probability to Poisson branching process

Tags: probability-theory, branching-process

Consider a random directed multigraph $D(n,r)$ on vertex set $[n] = \{1, \dots , n\}$, defined as follows. Let each vertex $i \in [n]$ have $r$ out-neighbours selected uniformly at random from $[n]$. Let $X$ be a random variable that indicates the size of the largest strongly connected component of this graph.

We know that as $n \to \infty$, $\frac{X}{n} \xrightarrow[]{P} \sigma(\mu)$, where $\sigma(\mu)$ is the survival probability of a Poisson branching process with parameter $\mu$.

> Is it possible to compute $\Pr(X > a)$?

Comment: Does $X$ depend on $n$?

Comment: @angryavian $X$ indicates the size of the largest strongly connected component of a directed random graph with $n$ vertices. Hence, $X$ depends on $n$

Comment: What is the distribution of the directed random graph? I am a little confused why you omitted a lot of this crucial information about $X_n$, and only stated the limiting behavior with no context.

Comment: @angryavian I updated the question